# How can I flatten my output text in Python if I use the nested for loop?

Tags: python

The challenge is to write a "F" letter using an inner loop without just multiplying the "X"

I want to flatten my output "F" letter using the following code.
Are there any ways to do it or in Python or this is the default console output?

```
numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]
for iteration in numbers:
    print('\n')
    for X in range(iteration):
        print('X', end="")
```

Comment: Err, your question isn’t very clear. Please give the output you get and what is wrong with it, or what you expect? And also please explain What “flatten my output text” mean?

Comment: `print('\n')` prints the newline that you want to print, plus the newline it puts by default at the end of every line. You can just print nothing (`print()`) if you want to get a single newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, we use '\r' instead of '\n':

```
numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]
for iteration in numbers:
    print('\r')
    for X in range(iteration):
        print('X', end="")
```

output:

```
XXXXX
XX
XXXXX
XX
XX
```

or you can do a blank print:

```
numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]
for iteration in numbers:
    print()
    for X in range(iteration):
        print('X', end="")
```

output:

```
XXXXX
XX
XXXXX
XX
XX
```